WSL The system cannot find the path specified
WSL Windows Subsystem for Linux  The system cannot find the path specified.
I Was Uninstalled WSL and all distros last week but now I want to install it again please anyone help me I was trying it for last 2 days  but it gives me a same error i have enabled WSL in windows feature but why my CMD or PowerShell can  not recognize the WSL command
my OS Windows 11 home 23H2 latest version
sshot1
sshot2
I Have turn on and off Windows Subsytem for Linux feature many times but not resolved I want to enable WSL but the term WSL is not recognizable in powershell or CMD
